# "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined" in production react build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm working on a react app that uses some common files with a node.js project, including a `utils.js` file that contains utility functions:

```
exports.someUsefulObject = ....
exports.someUsefulFunction = ....
```

I typically use it in my project is through require statements like `const utils = require('./utils.js')`

It works perfectly fine through the react server but when I try it through a production build, I'm getting the following browser error:

[image]

I'm new to react and quite confused about why full source files would be included in the static production build.

Comment: Did you project have been created with create-react-app?

Comment: It did - and it was working for a while

Comment: Could you provide your tsconfig.json file?